# WebView HTTPS Redirect / MITM Research

Tags: ios, webview, https, proxy, man-in-the-middle

I'm doing a MITM research paper on iOS and Android focused on WebView / Hybrid Apps. This is my test setup:

- Open WIFI Hotspot
- iOS and Android Devices on the WIFI
- Linux machine with Apache Proxy on the WIFI
- ICMP Redirect (DoubleDirect), DNS or Forwarding to pipe all traffic through my Linux machine
- For www.example.com I have a valid certificate from a trusted CA

I want to redirect a WebView request to https://www.facebook.com/ to my own site https://www.example.com/ directly on my Apache Proxy, without the user noticing anything in a hybrid App.

If this possible and how can I do that?